# Double Integral with Trig Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is:
$$\int_{1/2}^1\left( \int_{\pi/y}^{2\pi}\sin(xy) \ dx\right) \ dy+\int_1^2\left(\int_\pi^{2\pi/y}\sin(xy) \ dx\right) \ dy$$
I've tried this but I'm stuck at
$$\int_{1/2}^1\dfrac{-\cos(2\pi y)}{y} \ dy + \int_1^2\dfrac{\cos(\pi y)}{y} \ dy-2\ln2 $$

How should I proceed from here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Juts put $x=\frac y 2$ in the second integral in your attempt. You will see that it cancels with the first term!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it ,  should i substitute $\frac{y}{2}$ in $\cos\pi y$?

Comment: Make the change of variable $x=\frac y 2$ in the integral. @simon